# visual studio 2019 cant exclude folder from build in .csproj

Tags: xml, visual-studio, compilation, visual-studio-2019, csproj

I am trying to exclude an entire folder from being build in my vscode project, I have edited my project file to look like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">



  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="NxTestware\........." />
    <Folder Include="NxTestware\.........." />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Resources.Extensions" Version="6.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
        <DefaultItemExcludes>NxTestware\**</DefaultItemExcludes>
    </PropertyGroup>
    
</Project>
```

In hopes that when I build/pack the project, it excludes my folder 'NxTestware'
[image]

I followed these instructions originally to use`<Compile` and `Exclude='` but that didn't work
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-exclude-files-from-the-build?view=vs-2022

So I instead went with `<DefaultItemExcludes>NxTestware\**</DefaultItemExcludes>`, but when I build/pack my project it still trys to build files in the NxTestware folder which causes errors.
Is it possible to tell my csproj file to exclude an entire folder?

Answer (score 0):

First, undo the changes you've made.

Add the tag below to your `.csproj` project file to exclude those files from the compiler.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="NxTestware\*.*" />
</ItemGroup>
```

You might want to add the following one to keep those files part of your project.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="NxTestware\*.*" />
</ItemGroup>
```

---

You can add them together to a single `<ItemGroup>`.

```
<ItemGroup>        
    <Compile Remove="NxTestware\*.*" />
    <None Include="NxTestware\*.*" />
</ItemGroup>
```